# Photoshop CC - How to paint along the border of a selection

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush, selections, borders

I have this image:
[image]

I want to paint a lighter blue on the left cliff that flows along the border like so:
[image]

Doing it by hand is very hard and messy. Is there any way to automate this? If so, how do you do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a quick go using Outer Glow.

Use the wand to select the left cliff.
Copy then paste, which will lift it to a new layer.
Add a Layer style - Outer Glow with high opacity, zero spread, size as your 'border' thickness, range 1% [& colour bright aqua just to make it very obvious ;) Technique soft or precise ..take your pick, depending on how hard you want the edge to be.

[image]

Stroke might also be an option, but you'd have to re-mask your outer edges.

Comment: I had never thought of that! Thanks for the help!